# Parse ios8 User Push Notification Actions

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, ios8

I've registered the Notification Action properly and confirmed with a call to [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].

I'm using Parse to assemble and send the push like this:

```
        NSString *pushMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ just directly asked: %@", [[PFUser currentUser] username], [self.question objectForKey:@"text"]];
        NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              pushMessage, @"alert",
                              @"questionNotification", @"category",
                              nil];

        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        [push setQuery:pushQuery];
        [push setData:data];
        [push sendPushInBackground];
```

The notification does get delivered to the device but it does not have any of the custom actions available that have been registered for the category.

At this point I feel like Parse cannot properly convey the category in the payload? Has anyone gotten them to work with Parse?

Edit:
This is the response I get from currentUserNotificationSettings that make me thing the action has been registered successfully:

```
<UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x14e3eaa0; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);categories: {(
<UIUserNotificationCategory: 0x14e54c40; identifier: questionNotification, actions: {
1 =     (
    "<UIMutableUserNotificationAction: 0x14e4b860; identifier: yupAction, title: YUP activationMode: UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground, isAuthenticationRequired:NO, isDestructive:NO>"
);}>)};>
```

Update: More research, in case anyone else is having this problem, when I output the userInfo received from the push notification I get:
`{aps = {alert = "m just directly asked: Abaxinj";}; category = "QUESTION_CATEGORY";}`

So it appears that Parse is putting the category field outside of the aps container, which is probably the problem.

Comment: Can anyone enlighten why this was downvoted? New to the community but trying to follow all conventions. I included code and tried to explain my problem-solving proces...Thanks!

Comment: Update, I've tested all other ios specific push commands Parse is documented to handle (badge, sound, content-available) and they all worked on device. So my instincts are that Parse just cannot handle the category field correctly yet, but still looking to confirm this...

Comment: Opened a bug with Parse, they confirmed they're not equipped to handle this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opened a bug with Parse, they confirmed they're not equipped to handle this yet. They said to check the Parse.com blog for updates when they add ios8's new functionality.